# Java hashmaps with Key of one as value of other

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two maps:

```
map1 = <K , V>
map2 = <V, someObject>
```

Is there a "graceful" way of outputting a result as:

```
map3 = <K, someObject>
```

One obvious way would be to iterate over map1 and do:

```
    for each entry in map1 {
    map3.put(entry.getKey(), map2.get(entry.getValue()))
}
```

Ideally, I would appreciate solutions compliant with Java 7; but a clever one with Java 8 would be good for education purposes

Thanks

Comment: Please read the Stream tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/, it will teach you how to do those basic operations with the Stream API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a Java 8 method that does this:

```
public static <K1, K2, V> Map<K1, V> java8Version(Map<K1, K2> first, Map<K2, V> second) {
  return first.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> second.containsKey(e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> second.get(e.getValue())));
}
```

Add optimizations and null checks as desired.

And here's the Java 7 version:

```
public static <K1, K2, V> Map<K1, V> java7Version(Map<K1, K2> first, Map<K2, V> second) {
  HashMap<K1, V> result = new HashMap<>(Math.min(first.size(), second.size()));
  for (Map.Entry<K1, K2> entry : first.entrySet()) {
    if (second.containsKey(entry.getValue()))
      result.put(entry.getKey(), second.get(entry.getValue()));
  }
  return result;
}
```

I guess I even like the Java 7 version better, as it's more understandable and more honest about its cost.

If you want to keep keys from the first map even if they aren't present in the second (or have the option to), then use these versions:

```
public static <K1, K2, V> Map<K1, V> java8VersionWithNulls(Map<K1, K2> first, Map<K2, V> second, boolean keepNulls) {
  return first.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> keepNulls || second.containsKey(e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> second.get(e.getValue())));
}

public static <K1, K2, V> Map<K1, V> java7VersionWithNulls(Map<K1, K2> first, Map<K2, V> second, boolean keepNulls) {
  HashMap<K1, V> result = new HashMap<>(second.size());
  for (Map.Entry<K1, K2> entry : first.entrySet()) {
    if (keepNulls || second.containsKey(entry.getValue()))
      result.put(entry.getKey(), second.get(entry.getValue()));
  }
  return result;
}
```

But personally I'd say don't do it. Null is evil.

All of the above use eager evaluation. If you want a lazy view that will reflect changes to the Maps, use [**Guava**](https://github.com/google/guava) and do something like this:

```
public static <K1, K2, V> Map<K1, V> guavaJava8Version(Map<K1, K2> first, Map<K2, V> second) {
  return Maps.transformValues(
    Maps.filterKeys(first, Predicates.in(second.keySet())),
    second::get);
}
```

or, with static imports:

```
public static <K1, K2, V> Map<K1, V> guavaJava8Version(Map<K1, K2> first, Map<K2, V> second) {
  return transformValues(filterKeys(first, in(second.keySet())), second::get);
}
```

The map returned by this should perform well enough for lookups and iterations (constant time if both are hash based), but you probably shouldn't call `size()` on it (or any of the collections it returns).

Comment: A detail : why do you filter elements not in the second map ? you could keep the association of the key with the null value returned by the second map (the filtering might make sense, but was not asked in the question).

Comment: @Thierry I don't like null values. But sure, if you want to have them, delete the line with the filter